# Left Join on Linq to Entity issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, left-join

I need to extract data from Orders table which are not assigned and assigned orders are in a different table Orders_Assigned. Below is my Linq to Entity Code.

---

**Issue**: I am not getting just the unassigned orders, rather it gets both the unassigned  and assigned orders. Below linq code has issues including the and clause **{and [Extent2].[CHEM_ID] IS NULL}**. Any suggestions as to how to get the correct sql in linq to entity code.

```
var query = from objOrder in context.ORDERS
                            join objOrderAssigned in context.ORDERS_ASSIGNED
                            on new { key1 = objOrder.CHEM_ID, key2 = objOrder.ORDER_NBR } equals new { key1 = objOrderAssigned.CHEM_ID, key2 = objOrderAssigned.ORDER_NO } into temptbl
                            from temp in temptbl.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where objOrder.ORDER_STATUS == "NEW"
                            select new Order
                            {
                                compoundid = temp.CHEM_ID,
                                orderno = objOrder.ORDER_NBR,
                                route = objOrder.ROUTE_CD,
                            };
```

When I look into the SQL Profile, I see that one the where clause is missing and not sure what I am missing here

**SQL generated by SQL Profile for the above Linq to Entity code** :

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[CHEM_ID] AS [CHEM_ID], 
[Project1].[ORDER_NBR] AS [ORDER_NBR], 
[Project1].[ROUTE_CD] AS [ROUTE_CD], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CHEM_ID] AS [CHEM_ID], 
    [Extent1].[ORDER_NBR] AS [ORDER_NBR], 
    [Extent1].[ROUTE_CD] AS [ROUTE_CD], 
    N'' AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[ORDERS] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ORDERS_ASSIGNED] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[CHEM_ID] = [Extent2].[CHEM_ID]) AND ([Extent1].[ORDER_NBR] = [Extent2].[ORDER_NO])
    WHERE 'NEW' = [Extent1].[ORDER_STATUS]
)  AS [Project1]
```

**SQL which produces the correct data**

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[CHEM_ID] AS [CHEM_ID], 
[Project1].[ORDER_NBR] AS [ORDER_NBR], 
[Project1].[ROUTE_CD] AS [ROUTE_CD], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CHEM_ID] AS [CHEM_ID], 
    [Extent1].[ORDER_NBR] AS [ORDER_NBR], 
    [Extent1].[ROUTE_CD] AS [ROUTE_CD], 
    N'' AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[ORDERS] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ORDERS_ASSIGNED] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[CHEM_ID] = [Extent2].[CHEM_ID]) AND ([Extent1].[ORDER_NBR] = [Extent2].[ORDER_NO])
    WHERE 'NEW' = [Extent1].[ORDER_STATUS]
    and [Extent2].[CHEM_ID] IS NULL
)  AS [Project1]
```

Comment: I believe you should check for nulls in the select part of your query when casting from left outered temp. Something like (temp != null) ? temp.CHEM_ID : null.

Comment: @JanneP CHEM_ID is an integer and not null column. I am not sure how to add the above lines in the Select as it would thrown an error indicating it is null. I need to include the AND clause in the where statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Below linq code has issues including the and clause {and [Extent2].[CHEM_ID] IS NULL}.

You forgot to include `null` check in the LINQ query `where` clause. The only specific here is that you can't check `temp.CHEM_ID` property because from C# compiler perspective it's non nullable, so you have to apply the check on `temp` object instead (EF is smart enough to translate it to correct SQL).

Here is the working query:

```
var query =
    from objOrder in context.ORDERS
    join objOrderAssigned in context.ORDERS_ASSIGNED
    on new { key1 = objOrder.CHEM_ID, key2 = objOrder.ORDER_NBR }
    equals new { key1 = objOrderAssigned.CHEM_ID, key2 = objOrderAssigned.ORDER_NO }
    into assignedOrders
    from objOrderAssigned in assignedOrders.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where objOrder.ORDER_STATUS == "NEW" && objOrderAssigned == null
    select new Order
    {
        compoundid = objOrder.CHEM_ID,
        orderno = objOrder.ORDER_NBR,
        route = objOrder.ROUTE_CD,
    };
```

Comment: Thanks you rock. I just changed from objOrderAssigned == null to objOrderAssigned.CHEM_ID == null